# Create current class default instance in its base class

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, static, metaclass

*Preamble:* I have objects, some of them could be created by default constructor and left without modifications, so such objects could be considered as "empty". Sometimes I need to verify whether some object is "empty" or not. It could be done in the following way (majik methods are implemented in the base class `Animal`):

```py
>>> a = Bird()
>>> b = Bird()
>>> a == b
True
>>> a == Bird()
True
```

So *the question:* is it possible (and if yes then how) to achieve such syntax:

```py
>>> a == Bird.default
True
```

At least this one (but the previous is sweeter):

```py
>>> a == a.default
True
```

*But:* with implementation of `default` in the base class `Animal` (*to not repeat it in all derived classes*):

```py
class Animal(object):
   ... tech stuff ...
        - obj comparison
        - obj representation
        - etc

class Bird(Animal):
   ... all about birds ...

class Fish(Animal):
   ... all about fishes ...
```

Of course I don't need solutions to have `Bird()` calling in `Animal` class :)

I'd like to have a kind of templating implemented in base class which will stamp out derived class default instance and store its unique copy in the derived class or instance property. I think it could be achieved by playing with metaclasses or so, but don't know how.

*Class default instance* could be considered as any object instantiated by `__init__()` of its class (without further object modification of course).

**UPDATE**

The system is flooded with objects and I just want to have a possibility to separate circulating of freshly (by default) created objects (which are useless to display for example) from already somehow modified one. I do it by:

```py
if a == Bird():
    . . .
```

I don't want creation of new object for comparison, intuitevly, I'd like to have one instance copy as etalon for the instances of this class to compare with. Objects are JSON-like and contain only properties (besides implicit `__str__`, `__call__`, `__eq__` methods), so I'd like to keep such style of using built-in Python features and avoid the using explicitly defined methods like `is_empty()` for example. It's like entering an object in the interactive shell and it prints it out calling `__str__`, it is implicit, but fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the first solution you should use a [*metaclass*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python/6581949#6581949).

For example:

```
def add_default_meta(name, bases, attrs):
    cls = type(name, bases, attrs)
    cls.default = cls()
    return cls
```

And use it as(assuming python3. In python2 set the `__metaclass__` attribute in the class body):

```
class Animal(object, metaclass=add_default_meta):
    # stuff

class NameClass(Animal, metaclass=add_default_meta):
    # stuff
```

Note that you have repeat the `metaclass=...` for *every* subclass of `Animal`.

If instead of a function you use a class and its `__new__` method to implement the metaclass, it can be inherited, i.e:

```
class AddDefaultMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        cls = super(AddDefaultMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        cls.default = cls()
        return cls
```

A different way to achieve the same effect is to use a class decorator:

```
def add_default(cls):
    cls.default = cls()
    return cls


@add_default
class Bird(Animal):
   # stuff
```

Again, you must use the decorator for *every* subclass.

If you want to achieve the second solution, i.e. to check `a == a.default`, then you can simply reimplement `Animal.__new__`:

```
class Animal(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not (args or kwargs) and not hasattr(cls, 'default'):
            cls.default = object.__new__(cls)
            return cls.default
        else:
            return object.__new__(cls)
```

This will create the empty instance whenever the first instance of the class is created and it is stored in the `default` attribute.

This means that you can do both:

```
a == a.default
```

and

```
a == Bird.default
```

**But** accessing `Bird.default` gives `AttributeError` if you didn't create any `Bird` instance.

---

Style note: `Bird.Default` looks very bad to me. `Default` is an instance of `Bird` not a type, hence you should use `lowercase_with_underscore` according to PEP 8.

In fact the whole thing looks fishy for me. You could simply have an `is_empty()` method. It's pretty easy to implement:

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # might require more complex condition
        self._is_empty = not (bool(args) or bool(kwargs))
    def is_empty(self):
        return self._is_empty
```

Then when the subclasses create an empty instance that doesn't pass any arguments to the base class the `_is_empty` attribute will be `True` and hence the inherited method will return `True` accordingly, while in the other cases some argument would be passed to the base class which would set `_is_empty` to `False`.

You can play around with this in order to obtain a more robust condition that works better with your subclasses.

Comment: Thanks for the style hint. You soultion: at first glance it works, but it makes all instances the same...

Comment: @rook Which solution? If you mean the `add_default_meta` as function then, as I wrote in the answer, you *must* specify the `metaclass=add_default_meta` when creating subclasses, otherwise the metaclass wont be called. Using the "class version" allows to avoid repeating this, since `Animal.__class__` will be the metaclass and not `type`.

Comment: I tested the second solution with `__new__` method. I prefered that one, because all was packed down in my long-suffering base class :) [grc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613496/create-current-class-default-instance-in-its-base-class/18614965#18614965) idea was good enough to avoid decorating in subclasses, but it makes all instances of the same type.

Comment: @rook you mean the one that implements `Animal.__new__`? I just tested on my machine and it works properly: `Bird.default` is a `Bird` instance, `Dog.default` a `Dog` instance etc. also creating the instances passing arguments correctly creates the objects. (I made a small fix to make it work correctly in python3 where a `TypeError` was raised due to different semantics of `object.__new__`)

Comment: yes, that part works perfectly, but now all instances are the same objects, i.e. just references to one object.

Comment: @rook You mean all *empty* instances? From your question I thought that it didn't matter if the empty object was always the same instance. Anyway I'll fix it now. However in this case you *must* also implement `__eq__` in `Animal`, otherwise differnt "empty" instances will compare unequal.

Comment: I already have `__eq__` in my `Animal`, my objects are fine comparable between each other. The issue with your solution that now all objects are the same instance, e.g. `a = Bird()` then `b = getBird('eagle')` makes `a.name` and `b.name` equal to `eagle`(but `a` is just created by `Bird()` and "empty").

Answer (score 1):

Another possible metaclass:

```
class DefaultType(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        new_cls = super(DefaultType, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        new_cls.default = new_cls()
        return new_cls
```

You only need to set the metaclass attribute for the Animal class, as all derived classes will inherit it:

```
class Animal(object):
    __metaclass__ = DefaultType
    # ...

class Bird(Animal):
    # ...
```

This allows you to use both:

```
a == Bird.default
```

and:

```
a == a.default
```